# Error when trying to homestead up Laravel

Tags: laravel, virtual-machine, virtualbox, homestead

I'm trying to make `homestead up` and then power on my virtual machine homestead-7 but I get this error:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "8656a6a0-f53d-4c09-aa5f-823cf6f0eb54", "--type", "headless               "]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'homestead-7' has terminated                unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be availab               le in 'C:\Users\Lluis\VirtualBox VMs\homestead-7\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap,                interface IMachine
```

I check the log but can't find what's wrong.

I tried to update virtual box but don't works.

Know where is the problem? I will be trying to solve it searching information about the error.

Thanks

Log error:

https://github.com/aws2-18/Error-Virtualbox/issues/1

Comment: Is there any useful information in `C:\Users\Lluis\VirtualBox VMs\homestead-7\Logs\VBoxHardening.log`?

Comment: "but can't find what's wrong" - So clear the log file, try again and post log to us to try to find what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but there is too much information. I will post a pic now, thanks :) @Subtlebot

Comment: I edit now the question, thanks! @Tpojka

Comment: I post a Link to my github and in Issues you can check it.

Comment: You didn't follow my ask: delete content from log file, save log file, try again `vagrant up` command and post newly created content.

Comment: I follow your ask. I copy the log file and delete the old one, when I make vagrant up it create the new log file with all the info @Tpojka thanks

Comment: There is log from 16th of this month. Delete all of that first and let us check actual message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161714/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-tpojka).

Comment: Check the chat when you can @Tpojka

Answer (score 1):

I will post my software cause this is the problem!

I try to update VirtualBox but this not solved the problem so I uninstalled and install again from official web page.

Virtual Box version: 5.2.4

OS: Windows 10

Vagrant Version: 2.0.1

I will test it and if all it's good I will close the question.

Thanks